# Office 2011 Mac: How to link existing excel chart to powerpoint?

Tags: macos, ms-office, powerpoint, excel-2011

how do I link an existing chart in an excel sheet into a powerpoint presentation in such a way that when I change the excel file is change the powerpoint will be changed, too?

I found http://goo.gl/GcQa8 But when I use this "Chart linked with excel data" the chart in powerpoint won't be updated.

edit: When chaning the data "behind" the chart in excel the chart in powerpoint will be changed. But when I change e.g. the title of the chart in excel it won't be changed in powerpoint.

Any help is welcome.
TIA,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems too me that you can't link charts. 
You have to copy and paste the chart. The chart isn't linked but the data is. So when I change the (raw) data the chart in powerpoint gets updated.